# Combine filtered data from multiple worksheets to a single worksheet

Tags: vba

Have a workbook which utilizes multiple worksheets (15+) that are used to hold numerous lines of manufacturer data. We select items for order by entering quantities desired via a specific column. WE use advanced filtering with copy to option to move all line items which contain quantities >0 to a specific area within each worksheet. The copy to range (P9:V3000) is identical for each worksheet. I would like to write a vba macro to copy and combine the advance filtered data from each worksheet to a separate worksheet within the workbook named (Equipment List). My challenge has been selecting only the cells that contain data below cells (P9:V9). P9:V9 is a header row, everything below (P10:V3000) is the data I wish to copy.

Below is the code I have used which is specific to one worksheet ("Ansul Equipment") The code works when I have more than one line item below (P9:V9). When I have only one item code line 
"Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select" selects every cell below P10:V10 even though they contain no data. What is the best way to select only the cells in range (P10:V3000) that contain data? Would like to loop through each worksheet if possible.

```
Sub PC_CombinedCopyTo_EquipmentList()
'Turn Off Screen Updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Clear the("Equipment List") Copy to Range via macro
Application.Run ("EquipmentList_ClearCTR")
'Set imax rows variable which will allow me to select the first blank cells below the header in the ("Equipment List") worksheet
Sheets("Equipment List").Select
iMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row**
'Copy Ansul ADF Equipment list
Sheets("Ansul Equipment").Select
Range("P10:V10").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Equipment List").Select
Range("A" & iMaxRows + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> Range("P10:V10").Select
>
> Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

This is normal, you select row 10 and you go xlDown, so the selection goes to the end of the worksheet.

Although I advice to avoid using `Select`, and to edit any Macro-generated code in order to remove this bad idiom, I suggest this as a quick fix:

```
Range("P10:V" & cells(Rows.count, "v").end(xlUp).Row).Select
```